# Convert output string into lowercase / uppercase in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I tried this simple assembly code that accepts and prints the inputted String. I wonder how am I going to convert string into lowercase output if I input string in uppercase or vice versa. I am a beginner in assembly language which the codes often make me confuse. Thanks.

here is the code:

```
org 100h  

mov dx, offset question1
mov ah, 09
int 21h

mov dx, offset temp1
mov ah,0ah
int 21h  

mov dx, offset msg
mov ah, 09
int 21h  

mov dx, offset msg1
mov ah, 09
int 21h 

mov dx, (offset temp1)+2
mov ah,09
int 21h   


ret
question1 db 10,13, "Enter your Name: $" 
temp1 db 20,0, 21 dup ('$')

msg db 10,13, "$" 
msg1 db 10,13, "You Are: $"
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, from the start of the string to the end, to convert to lowercase, if the value is between 65 and 90 (decimal), add 32 to it.

To convert to uppercase, if the character's value is between 97 and 122, subtract 32 from it.

From the 1st character, and for the length of the input string (until you hit the '$', make your comparison.